# Header file circular dependencies

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I have two files, `gui.hpp` and `util.hpp`. *The source code is in respective `.cpp` files*

**gui.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "util.hpp"
class Text_; //forward-declaration
typedef Text_* TextPtr;

//Things that use Text_ and TextPtr


class Text_{
//uses stuff from util.hpp
};
```

**util.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "gui.hpp"

std::vector<TextPtr> vec;
```

Unfortunately, this does not compile. They create random unrelated errors, so it's not worth posting them here. But, it all stems from each file depending on the other.

I can fix this by defining **util.hpp** as

```cpp
#include "gui.hpp"

class Text_; //Forward-declare

std::vector<Text_*> vec;
```

Why do I need to forward-declare `Text_` again when `gui.hpp` is already included?
How can I let `util.hpp` use `TextPtr` instead of `Text_*`

Comment: You have no header guard to avoid an inclusion loop.
Think about adding '#pragma once' at the beginning of your header files.
Most likely your "random unrelated errors" probably stem from having your definitions and declarations appear multiple times when your CCP files are compiled.

Comment: @TommyD Sorry, there is actually `#pragma once`. I just forgot to include it in the example.

Comment: `std::vector<TextPtr> vec;` should not be in a header that gets included by more than 1 cpp file.